# AWS lambda running shell script

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have the following Python code written as part of an AWS Lambda:

```
import json
import os
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    os.system("docker cp panaxeaA1/ panaxea:app/phdcode")
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps('Hello from Lambda!')
    }
```

Which returns the following error:

```

16:21:23
START RequestId: 5693fd73-debb-11e8-9a71-ff6726b7be00 Version: $LATEST

16:21:23
sh: docker: command not found

16:21:23
END RequestId: 5693fd73-debb-11e8-9a71-ff6726b7be00

16:21:23
REPORT RequestId: 5693fd73-debb-11e8-9a71-ff6726b7be00  Duration: 16.04 ms  Billed Duration: 100 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 18 MB
No newer events found at the moment. Retry.
```

Docker *is* installed on the instance though... Any advice? I was under the impression I could make cmd calls via python?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "Docker is installed on the instance"?

Answer (score 2):

> Docker is installed on the instance though... Any advice? I was under
>   the impression I could make cmd calls via python?

Which "instance" are you talking about?! You are not executing your lambda function on your own instance!

According to the documentation:

> [...]When a Lambda function is invoked, AWS Lambda launches an
>   execution context based on the configuration settings you provide. The
>   execution context is a **temporary** runtime environment that initializes
>   any external dependencies of your Lambda function code[...] -> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/running-lambda-code.html

In order to call commands you have to install/embbed the packages your function needs into your lambda deployment package. See: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-python-how-to-create-deployment-package.html

Hope it helps!